# Http redirect in MVC3 .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, http-redirect

So I have my site running in production and intermittently (yeah, uhoh)... these redirects don't seem to be happening

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    string newuserid = BizLayer.CreateUser();

    return RedirectToRoute("MyController/MyAction", new { userid = newuserid });
}
```

The user gets created fine, code definitely gets past generating newuserid, but the next controller action never gets entered. So I was wondering if I properly understand redirects. Does the new URL get sent back to the client before the new action is entered? Once Create() is entered, should processing in the next action be inevitable (assuming no crash in Bizlayer) or are there browser situations that could prevent it?

Here's where it should be going:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string userid, DateTime? date)
```

Here's the routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "MyController/MyAction", // Route name
      "MyController/MyAction/{userid}/{date}", // URL with parameters
      new
      {
          controller = "MyController",
          action = "MyAction",
          date = UrlParameter.Optional
      } // Parameter defaults
      );
```

Essentially I'm wondering, can the client reject an MVC redirect and prevent the redirect to a new controller action happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying all the values in the RouteValueDictionary? You may want to give that a shot...

```
RedirectToRoute(new { Controller = ..., Action=..., userid=...})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    string newuserid = BizLayer.CreateUser();

    return RedirectToRoute("MyController/MyAction", new { userid = newuserid, date = null });
}
```

Comment: That's just how I named my routes. RedirectToAction puts a ? parameter  in the URL, which I don't want.

Comment: I suspected that. You edit your sample code, so there's no misunderstanding =)

Comment: Sure, I've added the routing on there.

Comment: @BradThomas I've updated the answer, hopefully it's more in the line of what your asking.

Comment: Can't assign null to anonymous type property. I do already know that my code works (usually) with date = null

Comment: So my question then, is if some kind of robot is accessing the site, should the redirect always happen even in that case?

Comment: Yeah, I believe so, but I'm not 100% certain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
return RedirectToAction("MyAction", "MyController", new { userid = newuserid });
```

Comment: RedirectToAction puts a ? parameter in the URL, which I don't want.

Comment: If userid is in your route, it will added that to the url and not as a query string.